# Can file permission values be called octets?

Tags: permissions, terminology

I've talked today about the file permissions and used the word *octet* to describe the `rwx` unit. Then I wondered if this is a valid name. [An internet search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=chmod%20octet&t=ffab&ia=web) shows that it's used here and there. But I wondered if it's not a misuse of [the term for the byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)). Is this opinion based or is there some valid well-based answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost a question for [French language](https://french.stackexchange.com/)…

An *octet* is an 8-bit value, which can take 256 distinct values. An `rwx` unit is is a 3-bit value, which can take 8 distinct values. Using the word “octet” for an `rwx` unit would be misleading.

The reason *octet* gets used in English at all is that *byte* has two meanings: it can mean an 8-bit value, or a value of the smallest addressable unit in the memory of a computer. The second definition is the original one. The first definition came about because most computers had 8-bit bytes. *Octet* was coined in English to express “8-bit unit” unambiguously: if you implement a typical data format or a network protocol on a computer with 6-bit or 9-bit or 16-bit bytes, you still need to use octets to encode data.

*[Octet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet)* has several meanings in English, all of them fairly obscure. The oldest meaning is in [music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(music)), where it means an orchestra consisting of 8 instruments. By this logic, a grouping of three bits would be a ***[trio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trio_(music))***.

*Octet* is also used in chemistry, mostly in the expression *[octet rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_rule)*, to refer to a grouping of 8 electrons. I'm not aware of any similar word for 3, but there is a *duet rule* which is similar to the *octet rule*, so if there was a need for referring to a group of 3 electrons it would make sense to use *trio* too.

Instead of *trio*, you could use *[triple](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/triple)* or *[triplet](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/triplet)*, which are somewhat commonly used in computer programming to refer to a group of three things, a 3-element [tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple).

Presumably people use *octet* for a set of `rwx` bits because this set is commonly expressed with one *octal* digit. But it clashes with every other meaning of the word, so you shouldn't use it. Besides, Unix systems have file mode bits that don't fit in the `rwx` trios (e.g. setuid, setgid), and some have permission bits other than `r`, `w` and `x` (for example append-only, permission to delete). So it's better to use a term that doesn't depend on the number of bits. Just say “permission bits”.

Answer (score 3):

An octet is specifically eight bits; it avoids the potential ambiguity of the term “byte” which can (could) represent type sizes other than eight bits.

In the POSIX world, file permissions are [represented using twelve bits](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html).

It follows therefore that the term octet can’t accurately be used for file permissions. I suspect that the confusion comes, at least in some cases, from the fact that *octal* values are usually used to represent file permissions, and the terms “octal” and “octet” are very similar.

Comment: [The PDP-7 was used by Thompson for first version of UNIX](http://www.linfo.org/pdp-7.html), and it had 18-bit words.  18 is divisible by 3 and not by 4, so it was natural to represent binary data in octal rather than in hex (as IBM did).  That's why UNIX, Linux, etc. still tend to express some things in octal and provide tools that understand octal, and why the C language and others use the leading 0 convention to mean octal.  If UNIX and C were invented today, on 8-bit byte hardware, I imagine everything would be in hexadecimal and octal notation wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago, in a distant galaxy, when...
A *byte* is (was) the size of a single character (IBM used 8, a DEC we had could handle 6/7/8 bits/character with it's 36 bit words). Yes, byte sizes did vary. Machines used to be vastly different, scrounching a bit here or there was the wood heroes were made of.
When networks became standardized by TCP/IP, folks had to come up with a standard measure of size. Thus was born the *octet* of always exactly 8 bits.
I remember a class around 1990 when we first came know of nerworking, I sadly forget by who. He said "This is spelled 'o-c-t-e-t' and pronounced 'byte'". By then ASCII (and 8-bit bytes) were almost universal.
"Octet" is a netwoking term, meaning an 8'-bit unit.

Comment: 1990 BC or AD ?